# Shared Preferences in React Native

Tags: react-native, sharedpreferences, asyncstorage

Well, I have been messing around with react-native for a little bit and as far as I came to know about [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) and worked around with it, it seems to me that it is not enough good library to store user preference data, as it seems to very buggy, most of the times does not work, have to rerun reac-native run-android each time I need to test in debugger. Is there any alternative libraries or procedures which will give me a way to seamlessly store and retrieve user data
( preferably in a synchronous manner)

Comment: You can try realm. https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/

Comment: Does this act like shared preference? Or it will reload data once I restart the app?

Comment: Stored data will be available to you until you uninstall the app or manually delete the app storage.

Comment: If you are using redux i can recommend redux-persist